# Error: “git: 'submodule' is not a git command” on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS and git 2.18.1

Tags: command-line, 18.04, git

I am trying to use `git submodule` with git but on running

```
$ git submodule update --init --recursive
```

I get

```
git: 'submodule' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

I cannot find a solution online other than this question [Error: “git: 'submodule' is not a git command” on Intel Edison and git 2.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35159477/error-git-submodule-is-not-a-git-command-on-intel-edison-and-git-2-0-1) which does not work in my case.

Earlier, I installed git from the `apt-get` method. I faced this problem. Now, I have built Git from source as mentioned [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git#Installing-from-Source) but I skipped the part

> In order to be able to add the documentation in various formats (doc, html, info), these additional dependencies are required:
>
> `$ sudo dnf install asciidoc xmlto docbook2X`
>
> `$ sudo apt-get install asciidoc xmlto docbook2x`

as I don't need it. How should I get over it ?

Comment: Is your goal specifically to build `git` from source in such a way that `git submodule` works? I ask this because the build of `git` officially packaged for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (provided by the `git` package) has a working `submodule` command. If there's a reason you can't use that (or prefer not to), you may want to **[edit]** this question to include information about that.

Comment: No, my purpose is to use the `submodule` functionality of git...irrespective of how `git` is installed

Comment: Then install git from apt.

Comment: @muru I had done that previously but that didn't work too

Comment: @PeDro When you installed `git` from using `apt`, did the problem appear to be *exactly* the same as it does now, or were there any (even slight) differences? Also, what's the complete and exact output of `type -a git` and `git --version`? (I recommend making another **[edit]** to provide this information.)

Comment: Right now (after making from source), it shows `git version 2.18.1
`

Comment: `type -a git` is really the more important command, since it reveals where the `git` binary is that's actually being run, as well as whether or not there appear to be other installed `git` binaries in other locations.

Comment: Yeah, you were right. There is another git flavour installed. I see `git is /home/.../linux-devkit/sysroots/x86_64-arago-linux/usr/bin/git
` But it doesn't have a uninstall rule.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like I was mistaken in thinking `git` could be uninstalled with `make uninstall` after being installed with `make install`. Sorry about that! You should be able to uninstall it by figuring out what files it installed, but for now, I think you can work around the problem by ensuring that the directory that contains a properly working `git` executable appears in `$PATH` *before* any directories that contain broken (or otherwise inadequate) `git` executable. I'll overhaul my answer with information about this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108920/discussion-between-pe-dro-and-eliah-kagan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt install git` installs `git` from Ubuntu's repositories. This build of `git` has a working `submodule` command. I recommend installing `git` that way, unless you have a specific reason to do otherwise.

Although you should be able to build `git` from source code in such a way that `git submodule` works, for most people the best way to install `git` on Ubuntu is to install the Ubuntu package for it. The package is simply called `git`. It supports the `submodule` command.

Also, do try finding which `git` client might be troubling you. Run `type git` to locate it. Then remove this version and reinstall `git`.

To install the `git` package, run:

```bsh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
```

---

`git submodule` works for me on an 18.04 LTS system on which `git` was installed that way.

(There is also a `git-all` package, which installs additional tools and services. [Those instructions](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git#_installing_on_linux) suggest it, but I don't think most users ever need anything beyond what the `git` package provides. It won't hurt anything to install it, but if you just install `git` you can still install `git-all` later. The 18.04 LTS system on which I just tested `git submodule` does not have the `git-all` package, or most of its dependencies, installed.)

---

When a newly installed version of a program should offer new behavior but unexpectedly behaves the same as what you had before, often the cause is that what you had before is still running, rather than the new software. The `type` command can help diagnose this. Based on further investigation of your problem, that strongly appears to be what is going on.

When you ran `type -a git`, [it revealed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54572500#54572500) that you had multiple installations of `git` and that the one that was actually running (`/home/.../linux-devkit/sysroots/x86_64-arago-linux/usr/bin/git`) was different *both* from the one installed through Ubuntu's package manager *and* the one you recently installed from source.

If you don't need that one, it may be best to uninstall it. If you do need it, or cannot remove it for some reason -- and also in the mean time, before you do remove it -- you can work around the problem by ensuring that the directory that contains a properly working `git` executable appears in `$PATH` *before* that one.

If it is acceptable to put `/usr/bin` in `$PATH` *before* `/home/.../linux-devkit/sysroots/x86_64-arago-linux/usr/bin`, that will solve the problem.

But that might not be acceptable. Perhaps you're relying on other executables being found first in that other bin directory. In that case, you could put a symlink to `/usr/bin/git` in some other directory that is earlier in your `$PATH` than that.

I recommend that approach over further breaking that `git` installation by renaming or deleting specific files such as `/home/.../linux-devkit/sysroots/x86_64-arago-linux/usr/bin/git`. The reason is that `git` has multiple executables, as some `git` commands are provided externally to the main `git` executable. Renaming (or deleting) some but not others could cause a situation where you're running one version of `git` that uses pieces of another version of `git`. This would probably work okay most of the time, but it would be complicated to troubleshoot when it didn't.

Comment: uninstalling from the `make`-directory, doesn't work. I get `make: *** No rule to make target 'uninstall'.  Stop.`

Comment: OK, So I removed this git client [by removing its PATH variable from the PATH](https://superuser.com/a/1558084/1143104). It works now :)